# Why do building prices change in Rome 2 Total war?

Tags: rome-2-total-war

I was going to upgrade my Roman City to Roman Colonia in one of my cities and I noticed that the price went up. One turn it was 3700 like it is on the Enclypedia (and also in one of my other provinces the price is still 3700), but one the turn I was supposed to start the upgrade, the price had went up to 5365, meaning 45% increase. I have no idea why this happened. Anyone else have ideas?

Comment: On the next turn it was 3200 or so, thus considerably cheaper than it should be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking back at the time, seems it was an earthquake that affected the construction price.
"Earthquake: +50% construction cost, -50% wealth from industry, -10 public order" I think one my generals had -5% construction cost trait so the total increase was 45%.